# unable to unzip zip file in linux centos

Tags: linux, centos

I am unable to unzip file in linux centos. Getting following error

End-of-central-directory signature not found.  Either this file is not
  a zipfile, or it constitutes one disk of a multi-part archive.  In the
  latter case the central directory and zipfile comment will be found on
  the last disk(s) of this archive.

Comment: What was your file and what your command? Might be helpful...

Comment: My file is a zip file and i executed the command  "unzip file.zip" , then I am getting the above mentioned error

Comment: Show us the output of "hexdump -C -n 100 file.zip". Is the file available for download somewhere ?

Comment: Look here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/54904/unzip-error-end-of-central-directory-signature-not-found  The second solution might work, although it is Ubuntu it might help in CentOS as well.

Comment: yes...I have downloded from one FTP location

Comment: jar xvf file.zip also not working.....it is not throwing any error but not creating the unzipped file

Comment: So tell us the link, then we can have a look at the file

Answer (score 0):

As you are mentioning `jar` in your comments we can consider this a programming question ;-)

First of all you should try to validate your file. If available you can even compare the checksum provided for this file and / or the filesize with the location you downloaded it from.

To verify the zip file on a low level you can use this command:

```
hexdump -C -n 100 file.zip
```

This will show you the first 100 bytes of the zips structure which will look similar to this:

```
00000000  50 4b 03 04 0a 00 00 00  00 00 88 43 65 47 11 7a  |PK.........CeG.z|
00000010  39 1e 15 00 00 00 15 00  00 00 0e 00 1c 00 66 69  |9.............fi|
00000020  6c 65 31 69 6e 7a 69 70  2e 74 78 74 55 54 09 00  |le1inzip.txtUT..|
00000030  03 0f 05 3b 56 2f 05 3b  56 75 78 0b 00 01 04 e8  |...;V/.;Vux.....|
00000040  03 00 00 04 e8 03 00 00  54 68 69 73 20 69 73 20  |........This is |
00000050  61 20 66 69 6c 65 0a 1b  5b 31 37 7e 0a 50 4b 03  |a file..[17~.PK.|
00000060  04 0a 00 00                                       |....|
```

The first two byte of the file have to be `PK`, if not the file is invalid. Some bytes later you will find the name of the first file stored. In this example it is `file1inzip.txt`.